# How to solve "Value Error: Cannot convert column into bool:" error in Databricks using Phyton?

Tags: python, databricks, strftime

I have the following code in Python

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Alex', 'Ani'],
    'Birthday':['1992-03-22', '1995-06-17']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'], format="%Y-%m-%d") 
df['Yay'] = df['Birthday'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
print(df)
```

I am running this script in Databricks. But when I run this, I get the following error

"Value Error: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', etc when building DataFrame. When I run this in JupyterNotebook, it runs fine. What is causing the problem in Databricks?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't believe that code will cause that error.  Please post the whole traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this code snippet is cause that error. I have tested in our databricks environment for the confirmation and its works fine. [image]